# How to capture (0/32LK) (0/21x) and (3/17) in one regular expression

Tags: r, regex

I want to clean up some TNM entries, Here is an example:

```
structure(list(TNM = c("pT3 N0 (0/13)", "pT3 N2b (21/45l)", "pT3 N0 (0/32 LK)"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

               TNM
1    pT3 N0 (0/13)
2 pT3 N2b (21/45l)
3 pT3 N0 (0/32 LK)
```

So far I got this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(TNM = str_remove_all(TNM, '\\,|\\;|\\.'),
         TNM = str_replace_all(TNM, ' ', ''),
         TNM = str_replace_all(TNM, "x", "X")) %>% 
  mutate(N_count = str_extract(TNM, '\\(\\d+\\/\\d+\\)'))

            TNM N_count
1    pT3N0(0/13)  (0/13)
2 pT3N2b(21/45l)    <NA>
3  pT3N0(0/32LK)    <NA>
```

This works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(TNM = str_remove_all(TNM, '\\,|\\;|\\.'),
         TNM = str_replace_all(TNM, ' ', ''),
         TNM = str_replace_all(TNM, "x", "X")) %>% 
  mutate(N_count = str_extract(TNM, '\\(\\d+\\/\\d+\\)|\\(\\d+\\/\\d+\\w\\)|\\(\\d+\\/\\d+\\w+\\)'))

    TNM  N_count
1    pT3N0(0/13)   (0/13)
2 pT3N2b(21/45l) (21/45l)
3  pT3N0(0/32LK) (0/32LK)
```

**Is there a way to shorten this regex:**
`'\\(\\d+\\/\\d+\\)|\\(\\d+\\/\\d+\\w\\)|\\(\\d+\\/\\d+\\w+\\)'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the alternation, you want to match no, a single or 1 or more word characters.

You could shorten the pattern not using the alternation and repeating optional word characters

```
\\(\\d+/\\d+\\w*\\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R034yV/1)

To also match `(0/32 LK)` and not only trailing spaces like `(21/45 )` , you can optionally match optional whitespace characters followed by 1+ word characters:

```
\\(\\d+/\\d+(?:\\s*\\w+)?\\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PZZ15v/1) | [R demo](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyczqSixqFKjuKQoMy@9SJOLK8TPV8FWIVlDqSDEWMHPQEHDQN/QWFNJRwEiYJSkoGFkqG9imoMQAysyNlLw8UYRAytT0FQCGgo0Pj61oqQoMblEA2iBjoJ6TIxGTEyKtj6I0LC3iokp1oqJKdfWtI@J0VTX/P8fAA)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was sure that I already tried this. Anyway now I see clearer!